# Python Discord bot not reading files

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have been working on a .`.joke` function for my discord bot where it reads a file with a list of jokes and picks a random one. When the `.joke` is run nothing happens, no errors, nothing. After a bit of debugging I found the problem is where it is opening the file. But when I run the read function in a different file (on its own) it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class joke(commands.Cog):
     def __init__(self, client):
         self.client = client

     @commands.Cog.listener()
     async def on_ready(self):
          print("loaded!")

     @commands.command()
     async def joke(self, ctx):
          file = open("jokes.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") #it appears it stops working here
          jokes = file.readlines()
          ctx.send(random.choice(jokes))

def setup(client):
     client.add_cog(joke(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `await` before `ctx.send`. Example this function (I don't use `self` because it is not a class):

```py
@client.command()
async def joke(ctx):
    with open("joke.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        await ctx.send(random.choice(file.readlines()))
```

And better use `with open` instead of `open` because you forgot to add `file.close()`.

Your code:

```py
@commands.command()
async def joke(self, ctx):
    file = open("jokes.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") #it appears it stops working here
    jokes = file.readlines()
    await ctx.send(random.choice(jokes))
```

Comment: I am currently using this in a cog, that's why I am using `@commands.command()` and also self in the function. I just tried your suggestion but no luck. I get no errors in terminal. I also tried it in the main python file and that didn't work either. It still looks like an issue when it is opening the file.

Comment: Do you add `await` before `ctx.send`? Because it's async function and you need to add await.

Comment: I add `await` in your code and it works well for me.

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: just tried the new code, still not working :/. I checked the file perms for it and they are all correct, also tried running as sudo and it still didn't work. I also have `await ctx.send` - could this have any difference that I am using a Raspberry Pi to run it? I doubt it.